# C# how to CC myself

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a VSTO project for Outlook. Very simple application with an icon on the ribbon. When user clicks on it, the selected email will be sent to the manager. It is working with the following code. But I want to add the sender as CC in the email. So whenever user clicks on it, the selected email will be sent to the manager and the user will be CC'd on it. So user will get a copy too. How can I CC the sender?
here is the code:

```
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        try
        {
            //get selected mail item
            Object selectedObject = application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            Outlook.MailItem selectedMail = (Outlook.MailItem)selectedObject;

            //create message
            Outlook.MailItem newMail = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
            newMail.To = "email@gmail.com";
            newMail.CC = Outlook.Account;

            newMail.Subject = "Subject Here";
            newMail.Attachments.Add(selectedMail, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem);

            newMail.Send();
            selectedMail.Delete();

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Message has been sent! You have been CC'd.");
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You must select a message to report.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've noticed the following line of code in the event handler:

```
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
```

There is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance in the ribbon event handler if you develop VSTO based add-in for Outlook. Instead, you need to use the `ThisAddIn.Application` property. You can start writing your VSTO Add-in code in the ThisAddIn class. Visual Studio automatically generates this class in the `ThisAddIn.vb` (in Visual Basic) or `ThisAddIn.cs` (in C#) code file in your VSTO Add-in project. The Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime automatically instantiates this class for you when the Microsoft Office application loads your VSTO Add-in. To access the object model of the host application, use the `Application` field of the `ThisAddIn` class. This field returns an object that represents the current instance of the host application. See [Program VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019#use-the-thisaddin-class) for more information.

Use the [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method to add new recipients to the email. For example, a raw sketch:

```
var recipient = Item.Recipients.Add(ThisAddIn.Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI").CurrentUser.Address);
recipient.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
```